# How to be able to type in desired value when value has been changed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html-select

I have a massive select with all the books of the bible listed, then attached an AJAX request being sent out for a PHP script. I want users to be able to type in the first couple of letters of the desired book, and the browser is currently looking for a value that has been changed to a number. Such as:

```
<option value="1" onchange="change_book();">Genesis</option>
```

How do I either A) Have JavaScript look for another, unique value or B) have the browser render something else I'm not aware of?

Comment: A bit more of your html and javascript code would be nice. Maybe ChosenJS: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ provides everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you can't bind an `onchange` event to an `<option>` tag because those don't change. `<select>` does.

Second, you mention typing. It sounds like you want something like [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Select2 select box library, specifically [Loading Remote Data](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#ajax)